# Conditionally Add Day to Date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I'm trying to conditionally add 1 day to my date. I have a dataframe DF, with variables `ID, FIRST, LAST, FORMATTEDDATE`. When strings in the LAST column contain an 'a', I would like to add 1 day to the FORMATTEDDATE and if it does not contain an "a", i would like to keep the FORMATTEDDATE  as is.

The dtypes for the variables of interest are:

```
Last                     object
FormattedDate    datetime64[ns]
```

CURRENT DATASET

```
ID  LAST  FormattedDate  
   1   7a    2020-01-01
   2   7p    2020-01-01
   3   2a    2020-01-01
```

DESIRED DATASET

```
ID  LAST       DateUpdate
   1   7a    2020-01-02
   2   7p    2020-01-01
   3   2a    2020-01-02
```

To get my feet wet in adding dates, I wrote the following code which works:

```
DF["DateUpdate"] = DF.FormattedDate+ timedelta(days=1) #add your timedelta
```

However, and like I explained above, I would like to apply this conditionally and to do so, wrote the following code:

```
DF["DateUpdate"]=np.where(DF["Last"].str.contains("a"),FormattedDate + timedelta(days=1),FormattedDate)
```

When running this code, I get an error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-57f35bb7a1b2> in <module>
----> 1 DF["DateUpdate"]=np.where(DF["Last"].str.contains("a"),FormattedDate + timedelta(days=1),FormattedDate)

NameError: name 'FormattedDate' is not defined
```

I'm reading about this error here but not quite sure why its popping up because the FormattedDate variable is housed within my dataframe.
https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/people/mccann/errors-python#Four

Comment: `DF["DateUpdate"] = DF["DateUpdate"].apply(your_function_which_use_if_else_to_test-it)`

Comment: `DF["DateUpdate"][ DF["Last"].str.contains("a") ] += timedelta(days=1)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your code

```
DF["DateUpdate"]=np.where(DF["Last"].str.contains("a"),DF.FormattedDate + timedelta(days=1),DF.FormattedDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you don't actually have a variable called "FormattedDate" in your DataFrame. You have a column labeled with that name. Despite the fact that you can access columns in your DataFrame *like* a variable (e.g. `df.column`), it doesn't necessarily behave like a variable and can't be referenced by name alone unless you're manually assigning that column as a Series to a variable with the same name. This is part of the reason why I prefer to access columns with `df["column"]`.

A standard way to handle this in pandas would be with the `apply()` method.

```
DF["DateUpdate"] = DF.apply(lambda x: x['FormattedDate'] + timedelta(days=1) 
                            if 'a' in x['Last'] else x['FormattedDate'],
                            axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you this is very informative, new to Python so I will research how apply and lambda work. I also get an error with this code, but I'm sure its due to something I'm doing wrong: TypeError: ("argument of type 'float' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 771')

Comment: Did you do this exact code? What code do you have before this?  What datatypes do your columns have? The expected iterable would be the DataFrame itself, with each element being a row of the DataFrame. My guess is that something is off there that is causing it to iterate a float instead of the DataFrame. Is there somewhere that DF is reassigned as a float?

Comment: Also, if you're new with using ```apply```, note the differences between using it on a DataFrame and using it on a Series. What x represents in either case and whether you have to specify an axis differs.